# Cursor Change by MouseMove Event doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, mouse

i've got some problem with my Mouse Cursor. I set it inside my MouseMotion Event of a JPanel with this.setCursor(), but it dosen't changed. 
After getting out ouf the Window for example on my Desktop and go back inside , the cursor will be changed by any motion.

The Code of the mouse Event of the JPanel is this:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    this.requestFocusInWindow();
    this.requestFocus();


    this.cL.doMouseMoved(e);
}
```

The Code of the Method doMouseMoved is this:

```
public void doMouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    this.lastMouseEvent = e;
    this.sList.setCurrentElements(e.getPoint());
    this.setMovedCursor(e);

}
```

An finally this is the code of the method setMovedCursor:

```
public void setMovedCursor(MouseEvent e) {
 java.awt.Cursor cu = new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR);
 view.setCursor(cu);
}
```

(I know that this isn't the best way)

I hope everyone can help me. 
Sorry for any mistakes, it's my first post at stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (sList.getCurrentShapeType() == "rec") {
```

Not sure if it will fix your problem but don't use "==" to compare objects.

Instead you should be using the `equals(...)` method.

```
if ("rec".equals(sList.getCurrentShapeType()) {
```

Note: I changed the order of the test so you don't have to worry about the getCurrentShapeType() method returning a null value.

```
else if (k.getBorderByPoint(e.getPoint()) == 4)
```

Also, I don't know what your getBorderByPoint() method does but why are you comparing it to an integer value. We have no idea what "4" means. Don't use "magic numbers. Instead create variables like: CURSOR_NORTH. Or better yet why not just return the cursor from that method so you don't have to check the value twice.

Comment: i am sure that this isn't the problem because the method will work when i left the window and go back inside with the mouse.

Comment: @domKi, first fix the code and then make the comment. Then you don't have to guess. Then if it doesn't work post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i hope it's better now.

Comment: @domKi, That is NOT a `SSCCE`. Create a JFrame, with a JPanel and add the MouseMotionListener to the panel. It should take 15-20 lines to post a proper SSCCE that compiles and executes. Chances are you will find your problem while creaing the SSCCE.